# Connection Refused on Google Compute Engine (container)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, docker-container

I hosted a python app on the Google Compute Engine using the container.
The container was working perfectly on the Google cloud run, but the server is refusing connection when it is hosted on Compute Engine.

My firewall config is:
[image]

Docker file:
[image]

wsgi.py file:
[image]

Log:
[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: first I uploaded the container to "Google Container Registry", then from there I'm directly deploying it to the compute engine. I did not get any errors in the log, But I got few warnings. I updated my question with the log.

Comment: is there any way to check whether my container is started or not?

Comment: You can ssh to your Compute Engine instance and run `docker ps`.

Comment: @norbjd Yes, it seems like my docker is running. It says uptime 7 mins.

Comment: @Soorya did you expose the application port (8080) ?

Comment: @norbjd yes I did. Now it got fixed. The problem is, the container is starting after a long time (like 10 mins after the instance is created). thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Soorya great :) I've experienced once a long startup time on Container-Optimized OS, caused by a too small machine type (I was using the smallest machine type).

Answer (score 0):

In a summary, this got fixed over the time, as the container started ~10min after the instance is created.

SSH the container node, and running `docker ps` shows that the docker was running, and the application port (8080) was exposed.